# ADO.Net EF4 CTP Release - New Project

Tags: entity-framework-4, ado.net

I am starting on a new large project and I'd like to use EF4 for the data layer stuff, mainly for the POCO mappings feature.

Am I a fool for stating work against a CTP release? Should I wait for the RTM? Given my project will likley take 12 months, could the RTM be out by the end of my project?

I'm sure others have been in the same situation as myself, what did you do and how did you come to that conclusion? I believe that given its CTP 4, the framework shouldn't change all that much, just bug fixes and any new features meaning a the code already laid should remain good.

I'd much rather use this than nHibernate or Linq as it appears (for what I want) to be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar situation with a project planned for release in about 6 months.  I am therefore fully behind EF4 CTP and thoroughly recomend using it.  There are a few shortcomings at present so there may well be a few changes between now and release, but I am prepared to take the hit on those to get the new functionality early.

Comment: Good to hear you recomend it! From what I can see it looks very much like what Linq to SQL should have been. I really wish they had some published timetable that us devs could work towards or around!